# How to make a msi installer which contains a install util program with none specified .Net frameworks in Win7 and Win8

Tags: installation, windows-installer, clickonce

I'm working for a installer program, I set the installer environment as following list:

1. The installer project was build with VS2010 .Net framework 4.0
2. It contains an assembly file which was build in .Net framework 4.0
3. The .Net frameworks version property was set with "Any" in launch conditions.
4. A install utility assembly which derived from Installer was built with .Net framework 4.0.

I test the installer in Win7, but the .Net frameworks 4.0 is essential. Then, I want to install the program to Win8, An exception which was descript as "InstallUtilLib.dll, Unknown Error" was thrown, then the installer rolled back.

I want to make an installer program which can be installed either Win7 or Win8 and none specified .Net frameworks version. What should I do for the scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the installer class custom action to use Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).  It's the gold standard for managed code custom actions and has a CustomAction.Config (XML) that supports the CLR's ability to specify supported runtimes and activation policies.

More information can be found at:

[Deployment Tools Foundation joins the WiX toolset](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/5/16/Deployment-Tools-Foundation-joins-the-WiX-toolset)

[Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) Managed Custom Actions](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-managed.html)

[WiX and DTF: Introduction](http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/09/03/)

Comment: I think your primary answer should be how to do it with the Visual Studio installer and then if you prefer add information about using Wix. I personally don't want to use or install Wix, I have a simple situation and I'd like to stick with the included tools in VS.

Comment: Sorry, the (no longer) included tools are garbage.